# C# DateTime to SQL DateTime losing precision

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Have a small problem where if I save a DateTime field as an SQL command parameter it loses precision, like often less than a milisecond.

e.g. The parameter's `Value` is:
`TimeOfDay  {16:59:35.4002017}`

But its `SqlValue` is:
`TimeOfDay  {16:59:35.4000000}`
And that's the time that's saved in the database.

Now I'm not particularly bothered about a couple of microseconds, but it causes problems later on when I'm comparing values, they show up as not equal. 
(Also in some comparisons the type of the field is not known until run-time so I'm not even sure at dev-time whether I'll even need special DateTime "rounding" logic)

Is there any easy fix for this when adding the parameter?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. - missing table definitions.

Comment: we can't say anything until you show your code!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using `DateTime`, which is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) with:

> Accuracy: Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

It sounds like you want [`DateTime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx):

> Precision, scale: 0 to 7 digits, with an accuracy of 100ns. The default precision is 7 digits.

That 100ns precision is the same as `DateTime` (1 tick = 100ns)

Or just live with the difference and write methods to round `DateTime` before comparing - that may end up being simpler.

Answer (score 3):

Try using datetime2 it has better precision.